# Clone Linux instance before reinstalling Windows

Tags: linux, windows, partitioning

I want to reinstall my Windows operating system. By reinstalling I mean deleting current instance and installing new. Just as a side note I'm going to delete Windows 10 and install Windows 7, but it shouldn't really matter.

The problem is I have a Linux (Debian) instance on the same drive and want to keep its state. As far as I know installing Windows always formats the drive, so I would like to clone my Debian instance to some external drive and after installing Windows 7 move Linux back.

Is there any way of doing this?

[Disk layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsNZY.png)

lsblk:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 223.6G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   500M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0   129G  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0  14.9G  0 part /
├─sda4   8:4    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0   3.7G  0 part /home
└─sda6   8:6    0   7.5G  0 part [SWAP]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though you can easily clone the Linux partition using dd or even a "live" (bootable) USB with WinPE and Macrium Reflect, you'll also need to keep the *boot* partition.

I've not had much success restoring Linux from an image, after reinstalling Windows, though. Reinstalling Linux from a Live distro and *then* restoring the old Linux partition has been easier. Even so, you may need to change grub a bit afterwards.